# vb.net: select case issue

Tags: vb.net, select, if-statement, case

I have created a code that simply split a text into lines and then get each line in a text box and compare it to several words so i choose "select case" statement to do the comparison
hear is my code:

this is the code that gives me line by line

```
 Dim TEXT As String
    Dim arraytext() As String
        TEXT = textbox1.Text

        arraytext = TEXT.Split(vbCrLf)

        lines = textbox1.LinesCount

        textbox2.text = arraytext(i)

        textbox2.text = textbox2.text.ToUpper()
```

then  i compare each line from the text by using this:

```
Select Case True
            Case textbox2.text="BANK0"
                textbox3.Text = textbox3.Text & "BANK0" & vbNewLine
            Case textbox2.text="BANK1"
                textbox3.Text = textbox3.Text & "BANK1" & vbNewLine
            Case Else
                assem.Text = assem.Text & ";Error line " & i + 1 & vbNewLine
            end select
            'read next line
            i = i + 1
```

the problem is that it works only in the first line then it start going to the else case
i tried with the if else statement the same problem !!
note if ichange the code to this : it works like charm

```
Select Case True
            Case textbox2.text.contains("BANK0")
                textbox3.Text = textbox3.Text & "BANK0" & vbNewLine
            Case textbox2.text.contains("BANK1")
                textbox3.Text = textbox3.Text & "BANK1" & vbNewLine
            Case Else
                assem.Text = assem.Text & ";Error line " & i + 1 & vbNewLine
            end select
            'read next line
            i = i + 1
```

pleas help ; thx in advance :)

Comment: Sounds like you just need to use the 'Trim' method: e.g., Case textbox2.Text.Trim() = "BANK0"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the 'Trim' method and stop misusing Select Case ("Select Case True" is a common VB abuse of syntax)

```
Select Case textbox2.Text.Trim()
    Case "BANK0"
        textbox3.Text &= "BANK0" & vbNewLine
    Case "BANK1"
        textbox3.Text &= "BANK1" & vbNewLine
    Case Else
        assem.Text &= ";Error line " & i + 1 & vbNewLine
End Select
```

A little explanation of why I believe "Select Case True" is bad practice: all you are doing is  determining the first 'case' that is true - this is done more clearly by using If/ElseIf/Else syntax, not Select Case.

Answer (score 0):

If the comparison fails the `=` test but passes the `.Contains` test, the most likely explanation is that the value of `textbox2.text` isn't just "BANK0", but a string containing "BANK0" plus at least one other character.

Trailing blanks are a likely possibility.